# Applying group by then condition

Tags: python, pandas

How can the value of 'same_month=yes' be updated for entries grouped by "code" when the "Date" is identical?

below are examples of the data frame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'2023-01-02 00:00:00','01','2023',''],
                   [2,'2023-01-02 00:00:00','01','2023',''],
                   [3,'01/16/2023','01','2023',''],
                   [4,'01/17/2023','01','2023',''],
                   [5,'01/16/2023','01','2023',''],
                   [6,'02/13/2023','02','2023',''],
                   [7,'02/13/2023','02','2023',''],
                   [8,'02/13/2023','02','2023',''],
                   [9,'26/11/2018','11','2018',''],
                   [10,'26/11/2018','11','2018',''],
                   [11,'26/11/2018','11','2018',''],
                   [12,'26/11/2018','11','2018',''],
                   [13,'05/11/2018','11','2018',''],
                   [14,'09/11/2018','11','2018',''],

                  ],
                  columns=['Number','Date','Code','year','Same_Month'])

df
```

so the expected result is that all of them are yes except entries number (4,13,14)

Comment: You should copy the _text_ of your expected result and paste it here in a code block. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You also need to ask an actual question. "I want to do X" is not a question. See [ask]. Asking a good question usually involves you thinking about the problem, doing research, and trying something yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick?

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='mixed') #Ignore this line if already in datetime format
duplicates = df.duplicated(['Code','Date'], keep=False) #Find duplicate date values per code group
df.loc[duplicates, 'Same_Month'] = 'Yes' #Add yes where duplicates value is true
```

This produces a table like this when using the data provided:

| Date | Code | Year | Same_Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-02 | 01 | 2023 | Yes |
| 2023-01-02 | 01 | 2023 | Yes |
| 2023-01-16 | 01 | 2023 | Yes |
| 2023-01-17 | 01 | 2023 |  |
| 2023-01-16 | 01 | 2023 | Yes |
| 2023-02-13 | 02 | 2023 | Yes |
| 2023-02-13 | 02 | 2023 | Yes |
| 2023-02-13 | 02 | 2023 | Yes |
| 2018-11-26 | 11 | 2018 | Yes |
| 2018-11-26 | 11 | 2018 | Yes |
| 2018-11-26 | 11 | 2018 | Yes |
| 2018-11-26 | 11 | 2018 | Yes |
| 2018-05-11 | 11 | 2018 |  |
| 2018-09-11 | 11 | 2018 |  |

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2023-01-02 00:00:00','01','2023',''],
               ['2023-01-02 00:00:00','01','2023',''],
               ['01/16/2023','01','2023',''],
               ['01/17/2023','01','2023',''],
               ['01/16/2023','01','2023',''],
               ['02/13/2023','02','2023',''],
               ['02/13/2023','02','2023',''],
               ['02/13/2023','02','2023',''],
               ['26/11/2018','11','2018',''],
               ['26/11/2018','11','2018',''],
               ['26/11/2018','11','2018',''],
               ['26/11/2018','11','2018',''],
               ['05/11/2018','11','2018',''],
               ['09/11/2018','11','2018',''],

              ],
columns=['Date','Code','year','Same_Month'])

df['Same_Month']= df.groupby(["Date"]).transform('count') ['Same_Month']
df['Same_Month'] = df['Same_Month'].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x > 1 else 'No')
df
```

Output:

```
Date    Code    year    Same_Month
0   2023-01-02 00:00:00 01  2023    Yes
1   2023-01-02 00:00:00 01  2023    Yes
2   01/16/2023  01  2023    Yes
3   01/17/2023  01  2023    No
4   01/16/2023  01  2023    Yes
5   02/13/2023  02  2023    Yes
6   02/13/2023  02  2023    Yes
7   02/13/2023  02  2023    Yes
8   26/11/2018  11  2018    Yes
9   26/11/2018  11  2018    Yes
10  26/11/2018  11  2018    Yes
11  26/11/2018  11  2018    Yes
12  05/11/2018  11  2018    No
13  09/11/2018  11  2018    No
```